# Converting a JSON structured url to data in R

Tags: r, json, database, dataframe, url

I am currently stuck on a problem with converting data from an API url to an actual list or data frame. I have used the same functions on different url sites and there was no issue regarding these. However, on my latest attempt something seems to be off. I have tried the following ways:

```
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)
url <- "https://cds-api.bwin.com/bettingoffer/fixtures?x-bwin-accessid=NTZiMjk3OGMtNjU5Mi00NjA5LWI2MWItZmU4MDRhN2QxZmEz&lang=en&country=NL&offerMapping=Filtered&offerCategories=Gridable&sportIds=4&sortBy=Tags"

r <- GET(url)
raw_data_bwin <- fromJSON(content(r, "text"), simplifyVector = FALSE)
```

and

```
url <- "https://cds-api.bwin.com/bettingoffer/fixtures?x-bwin-accessid=NTZiMjk3OGMtNjU5Mi00NjA5LWI2MWItZmU4MDRhN2QxZmEz&lang=en&country=NL&offerMapping=Filtered&offerCategories=Gridable&sportIds=4&sortBy=Tags"

js <- url %>% 
  read_html() %>%
  html_text() 

js <- fromJSON(gsub("bettingoffer/fixtures?x-bwin-accessid=NTZiMjk3OGMtNjU5Mi00NjA5LWI2MWItZmU4MDRhN2QxZmEz&lang=en&country=NL&offerMapping=Filtered&offerCategories=Gridable&sportIds=4&sortBy=Tags", "", js))
```

The first piece of code gives the following error:

```
Error: lexical error: invalid char in json text.

<!DOCTYPE html> <html lang="en

(right here) ------^
```

and the second one gives this error:

```
Error: parse error: premature EOF

{"fixtures":[{"games":[],"parti

(right here) ------^
```

I am trying to understand more about getting data from API's and JSON structured data sets, but with my limited knowledge I cannot find a solution to this problem. Could anyone assist me with these errors?

Comment: Please remove confidential parts of your URLs. Apart from that, it seems like in the first case it downloads HTML instead of JSON. HTML, of cource, cannot be parsed as JSON. In the second case it seems like the client does not wait for the whole response - might be problem with a library.

Comment: So I get this error when I'm trying to read-in a JSON-lines (a streamable incarnation of JSON) file instead of regular JSON. The file suffix is the same, but you need to use `stream_in` instead of `fromJSON`. See Jeroen Ooms (author of `jsonlite`) post about it [here](https://www.opencpu.org/posts/jsonlite-streaming/).

Comment: @JanMares If I remove the access id the page will not load. Furthermore, for the first try it does work like this with for example:

`url <- "https://content.toto.nl/content-service/api/v1/q/event-list?orderEventsBy=displayOrder&maxMarkets=10&eventSortsIncluded=MTCH&includeChildMarkets=true&prioritisePrimaryMarkets=true&includeCommentary=true&includeMedia=true"

r <- GET(url)
raw_data_toto <- jsonlite::fromJSON(content(r, "text"), simplifyVector = FALSE)$data$events`

So that does not seem to be the issue and for R the best library to work with JSON data structures is jsonlite

Comment: @Nate I have tried that function however, now I get the following error 
`raw_data_bwin <- jsonlite::stream_in(content(r, "text"), simplifyVector = FALSE)
Error: Argument 'con' must be a connection.`

Comment: @Nate besides my previous comment, I cannot find a difference between the site mentioned in the problem and this one https://www.unibet.eu/sportsbook-feeds/views/filter/football/ which does work with the first way I tried to convert the data into R

Comment: @XRotterdam I did not mean `jsonlite` - more likely a problem with the HTTP client. Anyway, this URL returns 13 Mb of JSON - that's not very nice for anyone (parser, client). Maybe HTTP chunk encoding is what causes the parser to get only partial JSON.